# How to pass string to Beacon alte

Tags: altbeacon

I copied and edit this code in order to pass string by ALTEBeacon, but I can only see two characters for example String name = "Paulo" And I only see "Pa". I do not understand why. I used this method code.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        // Call some material design APIs here
        device.setText("supported");
        // new code
        String stringToTransmit = "Paulo";
        byte[] stringToTransmitAsAsciiBytes = stringToTransmit.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1(MY_MATCHING_IDENTIFIER.toString())
                .setId2(Identifier.fromBytes(stringToTransmitAsAsciiBytes, 0, 5, false).toString())
                .setId3("2")
                .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {255l}))
                .setBluetoothName(Identifier.fromBytes(stringToTransmitAsAsciiBytes, 0, 5, false).toString())
                .build();

               BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
        BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getActivity(), beaconParser);

        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
    }
```

and I recover with this code

```
for (Beacon b:beacons) {
                    //new

                        String receivedString = null;

                       // byte[] bytes = b.getId2().toByteArray();
                       byte[] bytes = b.getId2().toByteArray();
                        receivedString = null;

                        try {
                            receivedString = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "ASCII");


                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code attempts to store the string "Paulo" into the AltBeacon Id2 field.  The problem is that ASCII encoding uses one byte for each character, and the Id2 field is only two bytes long.  Therefore, the field only has room for two characters.  This is why you only see "Pa".

Comment: Thanks for your cordiality,and support,  I used the Id1 in order to pass the string, and It's work fine,  I saw all string, I will read the Alte-documentation  for better comprehension.